# attempting to copy structs is doing some weird things

Tags: c

I have a simple database project. I have a file that lists some classes (which are defined by struct class_t which holds 3 char arrays) and then I have an array of pointers `class_t *classes[MAX_CLASSES]` the prog is supposed to do 4 things. The user can:

1. list classes
2. add a class
3. delete a class
4. exit and save the changes back to the file.

So, for the sake of an explanation, let's give an example file:

```
5 \\used to state how many classes there are. this is my "class_count" variable
CS:250:VH1224
BIO:107:MG1110
PHRE:110:BH210
FREN:110:BH312
CS:260:VH1225
```

When I enter the delete function, it asks which class (based on it's class number which can be seen in list) to delete. Let's assume I delete class 1 (based on the file it would be CS 25 VH1224), I have some code that looks like:

```
int classnum = 0
if(answer == 1 && classes[(answer - 1)] != NULL)
    {
      classnum = answer - 1;
      free(classes[classnum]);
      classes[classnum] = (class_t*) malloc(sizeof(class_t));
      while(classnum <= MAX_CLASSES && classes[classnum] != NULL && classnum < class_count)
      {
        classes[classnum] = classes[(classnum + 1)];
        classnum++;
      }
    }
```

every other part of it works other than the copying. When I do the copying, my output, strangely, is:

1 :   24

2 : 107 MG1110 10

3 : 110 BH210 0

4 : 110 BH312 2

5 : 260 VH1225 25

Where does the 24 come from, and why does the rest of the stuff shift over and get a random number at the end after deleting the department?

Comment: Why do you allocate mmory for an element that you want to remove?

Comment: In `(answer == 1 && classes[(answer - 1)]`,  `answer -1` is always zero - why the expression?  What is `answer` an answer to?  The queston lacks context.

Comment: so i can copy the next one back down

Comment: `answer` it is an answer to "which one would you like to delete"

Comment: So why do you only ever do the deletion when the answer is 1?  If you select 2, nothing will happen - the code will be skipped.

Comment: Well, `classes` is probably an array of `MAX_CLASSES` pointers and these pointers are always there. The allocation provides space for the structures that are stored via these pointers, so you don't need it. (You overwrite it immediately.)

Comment: What is class_t ? Do you understand what happens when you use the assignment operator to 'copy' one structure to another?

Comment: You are not copying structs as the title suggests, you are moving _pointers to structs_.

Comment: A debugger is your best solution to this problem.  You can inspect the structures directly and see the effect of each operation as you step the code. I doubt that the root cause is in the code you have posted, although that has issues.

Comment: In the first iteration, at `classes[classnum] = classes[(classnum + 1)];` you overwrite the pointer to the previously allocated block, causing a memory leak.  Why are you moving the pointers at all? Just set the free'd pointer to NULL and skip null pointers when iterating.